rpm spec: How do you suppress the error 'Macro expanded in comment' without deleting the linke?
While troubleshooting issues with RPM .spec files, it is often convenient to comment lines from the %files section:
%files
#%{_datadir}/vala/vapi/libgdaui-%{apiver}.vapi

However, that can produce build errors like the following:
Macro expanded in comment on line 213: %{_datadir}/vala/vapi/libgdaui-%{apiver}.vapi

Question
Is there a way to tell rpmbuild to complete the build and treat "Macro expanded in comment" as a warning instead of an error?

Looking at RPM's source code, that's not a build error -- it's a warning. Mind, it's a warning that may trigger an error if your macro expands to multiple lines -- very often with the first line being commented out the remainder won't be valid executable code -- but that won't be the case in a files section, so in that specific context the warning is safe to ignore.

ref. https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/blob/8c7d8d94126a5e21be68a99b85476297b01ac31c/build/parseSpec.c#L285-L289

rpm >= 4.15 has a real commenting primitive in the way of M4-inspired %dnl (discard to next line). As the name implies, it simply discards anything to the next newline, and macros in the discarded part are naturally not expanded (credit to Panu Matilainen)

This already is a warning, not an error. In a %files section where macros are of the type you show (expanding to a subset of a single path, not a list of paths), it's harmless. Ignore it, or double up your %s (as the documents advise) to prevent it from happening (and then undo that when uncommenting the same content).
Only log messages with level CRIT trigger an automatic build failure. Log messages with level WARN are not even close.
You might also consider using macros rather than comments to disable things temporarily (%if 0).

Quoting from RPM's source code:
    if (*bufA != '\0' || *bufB != '\0')
        rpmlog(RPMLOG_WARNING,
        _("Macro expanded in comment on line %d: %s\n"),
        spec->lineNum, bufA);

As you can see, the only thing we do when detecting the case is logging a warning -- nothing else.

Good point about the possible multi-line expansion issue.  I was getting a failed to build RPM error at exit and it listed all of the Macro expanded in comment warnings, so perhaps I read the message incorrectly.  I did get the package to build with successfully comments containing macros, so thanks for your detailed response.

It is not always harmless. If the macro it was expanding was multi-line, then only the first line of the macro would be disabled. The rest of the macro would attempt to execute it. The proper solution is to double up the %%.

@AaronD.Marasco, quoting from the answer you responded to: where macros are of the type you show (expanding to a subset of a single path, not a list of paths) -- was that caveat somehow insufficient? Yes, of course escaping the % is the correct approach, but I don't expect anyone to give up editor shortcuts for (un)commenting during rapid debugging when it isn't strictly necessary (of course, before submitting finished work upstream, yes, it's an entirely appropriate ask).

@AaronD.Marasco, indeed, if you look at the comment directly before yours, which the OP added on this answer, you see that they acknowledged understanding that macros expanding to multiple lines could cause problems, so there's no question whatsoever that it was clearly communicated!

Another problem is the code in the comment. The line #%global foo something%(touch /tmp/foo) is ignored as a comment, but the macro is executed. So file /tmp/foo is created. And if instead of touch, you have some weird rm, then you will have a big problem...

@msuchy, ...I don't have a lot of sympathy for people who fail to sandbox their builds. (I mostly live in the NixOS world -- in a past life where I used Nix to build non-Nix-based distro images, I had the former spinning up a qemu VM with only the declared dependencies for each package, and then running each individual package build in transient mode where changes to disk never left memory, copying the final binaries out via a virtio filesystem dedicated to the purpose)
